# Extracting elements from a jsonlite parsed list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, jsonlite

I have imported data from a .json file into R via jsonlite. Unfortunately the data shows up as a 'List of 1' even though it contains multiple categories.

```
library(jsonlite)
wimbledon <- from JSON("wimbledon.json",flatten=TRUE)
```

I get the following when I open wimbledon in the global environment:

```
wimbledon                      List of 1
 graph_data: 'data.frame': 1 obs. of 2 variables:
 ..$ term:chr "wimbledon"
 ..$data: List of 1
 .. ..$: 'data.frame': 165 obs. of 3 variables:
 .. .. ..$ matches : int [1:165] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 .. .. ..$ year : int [1:165] 1851 1852 1853 1854 ...
```

My question is, is there any easy way to reference only the  $matches and $year as I would do in a data frame using wimbledon$matches and wimbledon$year? I am familiar with using wimbledon[[n]] to extract a certain element of a list. However, the issue here is that I seem to have parsed everything into a single list in jsonlite. Apologies that I cannot add a reproducible example. Any help you can give me in extracting the 'matches' and 'year' columns as separate data frame columns would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `wimbledon$graph_data$data[[1]]$matches`. The structure of the data is interesting - I can't recreate a data.frame with a single row (`graph_data`) where the second column is a list, I didn't think that was allowed.

Comment: @mattdevlin Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. Yes, I was confused about the structure too, but somehow it seems to be possible. Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are unnamed values in a list e.g.`$: 'data.frame': 165 obs. of 3 variables:`, the `var[[n]]` syntax is needed so

```
wimbledon$graph_data$data[[1]]$matches
```

and

```
wimbledon$graph_data$data[[1]]$year
```

will return the matches and years.